# Почему не работает border-width?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

Абзацы отображаются без границы:

```css
p.one {
  border-width: 2px;
}

p.two {
  border-width: thick;
}

p.three {
  border-width: 1px 4px 12px 3px;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
  Синтезатор
</p>
<p class="two">
  Синтезатор
</p>
<p class="three">
  Синтезатор
</p>
```

Comment: Ширину для `border` Вы задали, а сами `border` не обозначили.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Почему не работает border-width?

Потому что нужно задавать тип обводки - `border-style: solid;` [Подробнее на htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-style)

Тогда заработает и толщина обводки - `border-width: 2px;`

Цвет по-умолчанию черный, если нужен другой, то можно задать - `border-color: #color;`

Или все вместе записывается: `border: 2px solid red;`

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @hug Цвет по-умолчанию, если не задан явно в `border` или `border-color`, то равен или наследует значение свойства `color`.

Answer (score 6):

Универсальное свойство `border` позволяет одновременно установить толщину, стиль и цвет границы вокруг элемента. Значения могут идти в любом порядке, разделяясь пробелом, браузер сам определит, какое из них соответствует нужному свойству.

*Синтаксис:*

```
border: border-width || border-style || border-color;
```

Как написал @meine в комментариях, ширина для `border` задана, а сам `border` не обозначен.

Все работает:

```css
p.one {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 2px;
}
p.two {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: thick;
}
p.three {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 3px;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
   Синтезатор
  </p>
<p class="two">
   Синтезатор
</p>
<p class="three">
   Синтезатор
</p>
```